# Will Changing Nameservers Mess up Existing MX Records?

Tags: godaddy, hostgator

My client uses an existing domain for his email and it is parked at Godaddy. There are MX and TXT records that exist in Godaddy that point to Outlook/Exchange.

My question is: if I change the nameservers to HostGator, will those records get overwritten and stop his email from working? I want to make this as seamless as possible.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you change the nameservers away from the current Godaddy to HostGator (or other) then the Godaddy records will not be being used. So yes if you change the nameservers those records will be gone. You need to make sure that the dns you are transfering to is already setup with all the required records of the previous dns.